# ros installation on mac architecture symbol error

Tags: rosbuild, rosinstall, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
That is my first time programming on mac since I just bought a brand new mac book pro. When I try to install ros by following the wiki, I get this error :

```
 Linking CXX executable ../bin/rosplay
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet()", referenced from:
        ros::record::Player::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::Time, bool)in rosplay.o
    "boost::filesystem3::path::extension() const", referenced from:
        ros::record::Player::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::Time, bool)in rosplay.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/rosplay] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosplay.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
```

The architecture isn't x86 on a mac...so I don't really understand this error, does someone happen to know why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9591/ros-installation-on-mac-architecture-symbol-error./) by [MorganCormier](https://answers.ros.org/users/360/morgancormier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-07**:
All modern mac's are x86 as of a few year ago.  And in the last year or so they switched to 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2
```

immediately above the `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` line in `ros_comm/tools/ros_record/Player.h` at least gets it to build for me.

As yet untested; caveat compiler.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-13**:
Confirming that this will let the package build, but probably not a long-term solution to this problem.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-27**:
There's a ticket for a similar problem at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4923

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you try to adapt the CMakeLists.txt of the rosrecord package?
On line 22 (or close to it) you should change the line

```
rosbuild_link_boost(rosplay iostreams system)
```

to

```
rosbuild_link_boost(rosplay iostreams system filesystem)
```

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2011-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2011-05-21**:
Same error here. Adding the link to filesystem solved the issue. Thanks!